# Nextjs API req.query is originally undefined. Workaround to getting the query?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to check if the `req.query` is equal to the cookies from the site.  However, on first load, `req.query` is undefined.  Whats a workaround this?

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;
  const userId = req.query.id; //undefined
  const userCookieId = req.cookies?.uid || req.cookies?.guestId; //undefined
  const authUser = userId === userCookieId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know of is this

```js
const url = new URL(req.url)
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search)
const token = searchParams.get('token')
```

however i have only used this with next.js app router so I am unsure if it will work with your code